# Asynchronous Spring Remoting (AMQP) Client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I have a Spring Boot web application implementing the API Gateway pattern in which the embedded Tomcat instance receives requests and forwards them to a number of microservices (also Spring Boot applications). I'm using [Spring Remoting with AMQP](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.5.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#remoting) to establish communication and some of the calls to these services may take a while to complete (the most expensive one takes, say, 1-2 seconds).

I've successfully configured listener concurrency on these microservices and everything is working smooth, but now I'm wondering what the default behaviour of the client is. Are calls to those microservices made synchronously or asynchronously? And, in case they are synchronous by default, how can I make them asynchronous so that these calls don't block the "Tomcat" thread in which they're being made (making it available to process other requests while waiting for the response from the services)?

Comment: If you are really using Spring Remoting for that it is synchronous as it basically is a Remote Method Call and not messaging. If you don't want that don't use Spring Remoting put just send messages instead of doing remote method calls.

Comment: "If you are really using Spring Remoting for that (...)" — would I be better off using something else for that? Can you recommend on something?

Comment: What you now have is basically RPC, if you want messaging then use messaging which is async by default. With RPC you also have binary couling between your different services as they need to share some classes/interfaces. You have a client side proxy for a service in one of your other services.

Comment: "With RPC you also have binary couling between your different services as they need to share some classes/interfaces. You have a client side proxy for a service in one of your other services. " — Yes, this I'm aware of and it's OK, really. I'm just concerned about (potential) performance improvements here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1.6 release [introduces a new `AsyncRabbitTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#async-template). When calling the `sendAndReceive()` (and `convertSendAndReceive()`) methods, a `ListenableFuture` is returned with which you can register a callback to receive the reply.